# How to use criteria API for hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am working on Hibernate I have `Emp` table but I want to fetch the data like this

```
String query = "Select * from emp where ename='bhanu' or ename='hari' or ename='balu'";
```

How can I do this by using Hibernate Criteria API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need an or condition here? Can you not do an IN query instead? 
Also, i would suggest you look up the hibernate documentation for the criteria query API. It is pretty basic and will help you understand and structure your DB layer.

Here is how you do it using the Criteria API.

```
List employees = session.createCriteria(Emp.class)
    .add(Restrictions.or(
Restrictions.eq("ename", "bhanu") ,Restrictions.eq("ename", "hari") ,Restrictions.eq("ename", "balu") 
    ) )
    .list();
```

Comment: Hi IN is working fine but I want to apply LIKE also  for example I have query like this                                                               String query =select  * FROM emp WHERE empId LIKE '1740 %'
                          OR empId LIKE '%1938 '
                          OR empId LIKE '%1940 % test';             how can i write this in criteria API